# Swift 3: sorting arrays with sort function: seeing error of Ambiguous use of 'sort(comparator:)'

Tags: swift, swift3

This code generates this error:

> Ambiguous use of 'sort(comparator:)'

```
chars.sort {
    let s0 = $0 as? String
    let s1 = $1 as? String
    if array.index(of: s0) == array.index(of: s1) {
        ComparisonResult.orderedSame
    } else if array.index(of: s0) < array.index(of: s1) {
        ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
    } else {
        ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
    }
}
```

Other SO posts suggested casting the arguments of the `sort` function to Strings, but the error persists. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: How is `chars` defined? And what is `array`?

Comment: @appzYourLife that was the fix! please post an answer, that is making sure `chars` is a defined array and not `Any`.

Comment: I am still not sure about the problem here. Can you please tell me how `chars` and `array` are defined?

Comment: `Chars` was a value from a loop iteration of a Dictionary, hence it was defined as `Any`.

Comment: And `array` is defined as `[String]`?

Comment: @appzYourLife yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array like this

```
let chars: [Any] = ["g", "c", "a"]
```

and you want to sort it using the orders the elements into another array

```
let orders = ["a", "b", "c", "e", "f"]
```

you can simply write

```
let sorted = chars
    .flatMap { $0 as? String }
    .sorted { orders.index(of:$0) ?? Int.max < orders.index(of: $1) ?? Int.max }

// print(sorted) 
// ["a", "c", "g"]
```